# About SubSonic 3 (ActiveRecord) Queries

Tags: c#, .net, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm new to **SubSonic** (*v.3 ActiveRecord*) *also I'm not interested in linq before* and I couldn't find enough document or samples for **queries**.

For example I don't know how to login a member with known fields;

`Member.Exists(x => x.Email == Email);`  <=== How to write this for two fields? OR

`var Member = Member.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == Email);`  <=== How to write this for two fields?

Any documents, tutorials or samples would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found some solution for my question at least it's a start.

```
var Member = Members.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == Email && x.Password == Password);
```